# How to calculate group mean differences and effect size in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I want to use Students' Treatment Total Score and Control Group Total Score, and measure 'difference between the scores'. And then I want to measure effect size and Significance for each 'difference' score. How can I do this in SPSS?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you have two groups measured at only one time point.

You can use `Analyze - GLM - Univariate` and put group into fixed factor and treatment score into dependent variable. This is a more general tool which can also be used for factorial designs.

You can also use `Analyze - Compare means - Independent Groups T-test` in your case.

In terms of calculating effect size, I imagine you will want to calculate the standardised group mean difference (i.e., Cohen's d). The simplest approach to this is to take the group means and standard deviations and plug the values manually into a formula or online calculator. See for example [this calculator here](http://www.uccs.edu/~lbecker/) or one of the [group mean effect size formulas discussed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size#Effect_sizes_based_on_means_or_distances_between.2Famong_means).

Answer (score 0):

Please check in GLM ( most probably GLM1 ANOVA ).
There is also an example in SPSS help.
Also you can check this source:
http://www.cob.unt.edu/itds/faculty/evangelopoulos/busi6480/BUSI6480_HW4_solutions_Spring2009.pdf

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.